# Lossless HDCP stripper?

Tags: video, sync

Is there a product that allows you to strip HDCP from HDMI and that does not loose quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The companies [Spatz-Tech](http://www.spatz-tech.com/), [HDFury](http://www.hdfury.com/) and [Faroudja](http://www.faroudja.com/) have products with that functionality in their portfolio. But there are selling restrictions in many countries.